# Raster reprojection with D3

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, projection, map-projections

I'm trying to get my head around raster reprojection using D3's geo class and am a bit stuck. 
[This](http://bl.ocks.org/tomstove/5603701) is a copy of Mike Bostock's original code found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4329423). When running on my localhost the map is only showing a small portion around Alaska and British Columbia but the rest is blank. When using D3's orthographic projection I get the same problem as well. Also, I've tried using a Geotif file but that didn't load. Does the image have to be in JPEG format? Thanks in advance, Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the JavaScript console, you’ll see a SecurityError:

```
Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. bl.ocks.org:1
Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18
```

Canvas is subject to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Unless the image you are loading has the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) set, as soon as you draw the image from eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov into the canvas, the canvas becomes *tainted*. You are not allowed to read pixel values from a tainted canvas (because it could leak private information to a third-party).

You need to host a copy of this image on the same-domain as your page (e.g., the [blue-marble.jpg](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4329423/readme-blue-marble.jpg) used in the other example). Alternatively you could petition NASA to [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org) on their server, but that might take a while.

Comment: Thanks @mbostock. I like the petition idea but I'm not optimistic about it. Appreciate your response